# Do the stitches on Adidas shoes' foot (out sole) make the shoes more durable for walking?

Tags: walking, footwear, shoes

Are the stitches on Adidas shoes' foot (out sole) part for decor only, or do they **have a purpose for more durability** via sewing and gluing? (see on linked image, foot part with white stitches)

**I am asking this, because I would like to purchase it for long walk sessions on concrete terrain,**

I would like to **buy one but only if it is durable.** I think, that if they are indeed sewn, that would give more durability to it along with being already glued.  [image: shoe with white stitches on outsole]

---

Answer: Okay, so I went to a store and checked it, it is actually sewed. It is a bit hard, but one can feel the thread from the inside of the shoe.

Comment: I am sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question, please do redirect me to the correct one if that is the case. I have searched before posting it and the only questions regarding shoes where the only ones on this sub-site, hence choosing it as the place to ask my question. Since shoes are for outdoors, and this is outdoors.stackexchange I feel like it shouldn't be off-topic.

Comment: None taken. I can see the logic behind it and it is  true that i should have been phrased it more on-topic from start, it being related to walking. But anyways thanks for your honest feedback and suggestion. Was hoping that maybe someone here may know an answer for it, maybe even faster than Adidas would give any feedback to a sent email. I will contact them nonetheless.

Comment: As far as I'm aware all shoes like this are glued and the stitches are purely a decorative molding. It might be worth checking if they're real first.

Comment: @Separatrix thanks for your answer, I think it might be just as you said. I have to check it out, as I contacted some days ago Adidas, as suggested, but no response from them to this day.

Comment: Okay, so I went to a store and checked it, it is actually sewed. It is a bit hard, but one can feel the thread from the inside of the shoe.

Comment: Hi Anne Kate! Since you know the answer, it would help if the community saw it too! Would you like to put the text from your comment into the question as an addendum or follow up? As you know, comments here get deleted and I wouldn't want people to miss out on what you learned! It's up to you of course! I hope you're happy here and will keep contributing!

Comment: As a note on this, that's never been failure point for me on shoes. On hard surfaces I normally walk the soles off before any other failure.

Comment: Although I too normally walk the soles off than anything else, it happened more than once that after a half year or so, the gluing came off on one or more parts of the shoe. Hence I'm hoping that a sewing helps when it comes to durability and the sole of the shoe coming off.